# Openlayers 3 GeoJSON coordinates shows wrong result

Tags: angularjs, json, openlayers-3, geojson, coordinate-transformation

I am using angular-openlayers-directive to build my project.

I try to rewrite the [example](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/045-layers-geojson-example.html) of geojson part cause I will get point information dynamically. So I made the source part of geojson inside instead of loading from json file. However, the position of my code is totally different as I expect.

The result suppose to show a point at that coordinate I set. But the point is like at the [0, 0]. If I change the to use loading from the json file, that will work.

I have no idea why the coordinate change so much. If anyone know the reason why, please let me know! I will appreciate that.

The following is my code:

```
        source: {
            type: "GeoJSON",
            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
            geojson: {
                object: {
                    type: "FeatureCollection",

                    features: [{
                        type: "Feature",
                        id: "TWN",
                        properties: {
                            name: "Taiwan"
                        },
                        geometry: {
                            type: "Point",
                            coordinates: [25.038507, 121.525527]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
            //url: 'json/ESP.geo.json'
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the placement of the 'projection' attribute. The answer below shows the correct one.

```
source: {
        type: "GeoJSON",
        geojson: {
            object: {
                type: "FeatureCollection",

                features: [{
                    type: "Feature",
                    id: "TWN",
                    properties: {
                        name: "Taiwan"
                    },
                    geometry: {
                        type: "Point",
                        coordinates: [25.038507, 121.525527]
                    }
                }]
            },

            projection: 'EPSG:4326',
        }
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The GeoJSON you've supplied is invalid. GeoJSON coordinates pairs are in the form of longitude/latitude, not latitude/longitude as you've used for Taiwan. Switch them and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your answer~! That was a mistake I forgot to edit! I did switch the position of longitude and latitude. it doesn't work correctly as well. Interesting thing i tried is that the same file shows different result on my laptop with my coworker's.....