# Openlayers Angularjs always shows GeoJSON Point at [0,0]

Tags: angularjs, openlayers-3, geojson

The question is closest to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36079288/openlayers-3-geojson-coordinates-shows-wrong-result). But seems it hasn't been solved (and i am unable to comment on that), i would like to give more information.

First, I am using [Inline GeoJSON](http://tombatossals.github.io/angular-openlayers-directive/examples/055-layers-geojon-dynamic-load-example.html), trying to assign some random points, eg:

```
{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
           "type": "Point",
           "coordinates": [
                        99.140625,
                        9.44906182688142
                      ]
         }
};
```

The result is always at [0,0]. It has nothing to do with the longitude and latitude.

By the way, the example by the author is a boundary which, after tested, also not displayed. But here i would like to just test a single point first.

What did i miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"source": {
"type": "GeoJSON",
"geojson": {
  "object": {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "id": "op",
        "properties": {
          "name": "aaa"
        },
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -9.520376,
            38.231155
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "projection": "EPSG:4326"
}
```

Apparently, it is necessary to specify the projection information!
Thanks to pavlos as his code hints sth.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is the rest of your code but the geojson you provide is working fine.

check this snip

```
var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON();
var myGeoJsonFeatures = format.readFeatures(
myGeoJson, 
{featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'}
);
vector.getSource().addFeatures(myGeoJsonFeatures);
```

And a working fiddle [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p_tsagkis/1zjvebwt/).

Maybe it has to do with the projection you asign to the map

Comment: Hi, the normal OpenLayers is working. My question is about Openlayers in AngularJS.

Comment: Hi pavlos, thanks for your code btw. I post the answer. The projection info is to be included!